# onPlaybackNearlyFinished does not work

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have the following problem with Java on AWS lambda:

The Intent called "PlaybackNearlyFinished" does not work, aka, does not play the audio file I am feeding it. Can anybody crack exactly why this doesn't work?

Here is my Java Code:

```
@Override
  public SpeechletResponse onPlaybackFinished(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<PlaybackFinishedRequest>
                                                      speechletRequestEnvelope) {
    // logging info("onPlaybackFinished start");


    SpeechletResponse response = new SpeechletResponse();

    Stream stream = new Stream();
    stream.setToken("test mp3");
    stream.setUrl("https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3");
    stream.setOffsetInMilliseconds(0);

    AudioItem audioItem = new AudioItem();
    audioItem.setStream(stream);

    PlayDirective playDirective = new PlayDirective();
    playDirective.setAudioItem(audioItem);
    playDirective.setPlayBehavior(PlayBehavior.REPLACE_ALL);

    List<Directive> directives = new ArrayList<>();
    directives.add(playDirective);
    response.setDirectives(directives);
    response.setShouldEndSession(true);
    // logging info("onPlaybackFinished end, return testmp3");

    return response; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

a couple of points here:

1. The method you showed had the name of `onPlaybackFinished` while it should have been `onPlaybackNearlyFinished`
2. Looks like the new stream misses the expected previous token. It should be equal to the token of the stream that is finishing - `requestEnvelope.getRequest().getToken()`
3. I would also made it `PlayBehavior.ENQUEUE` instead of `PlayBehavior.REPLACE_ALL` but I am not sure here... still experimenting

Hope it helps!